# Integrating improper integral that seems to diverge

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Full disclosure this is a homework question. But I think the question is wrong, or maybe someone can help me understand my flaw.

[image]

I integrated each part separately and ended up with -k*ln(x)+(5/2)log(6+2x) (limit as x-> infinity)

But that seems to diverge for all values of k,  let me know if you think im missing something.

Comment: $\int (f(x)-g(x))dx$ may converge even when  $\int f(x)dx$ and  $\int g(x)dx$ both diverge.

Comment: Reduce to the common denominator under the integral, and select the value of $k$ that turns the coefficient of $x$ in the numerator into $0$ ($k=5/2$). Then your integrand will decrease as $\frac1{x^2}$ and the integral will converge. Otherwise it decreases as $\frac1{x}$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: It's $(5-2k)x-6k$, so $k=5/2$ only leaves $-6k=-15$, a constant.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for the answer, I just checked it and it does work, now I just need to rework it until I can figure out how to get there on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{2x+6}-\frac{k}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\left[\frac{5}{2}\ln(2x+6)-k\ln(x)\right]\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}=\ln\left(\frac{(2x+6)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{x^{k}}\right)\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln \left(\frac{(2x+6)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{x^k}\right)-\ln\left(8^{\frac{5}{2}}\right)$$

Then note that $$\frac{(2x+6)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{x^k}\rightarrow\begin{cases} 0 \space\space\space\text{if $k>\frac{5}{2}$}\\ 4\sqrt{2} \space\space\text{if $k=\frac{5}{2}$} \\ \infty \space\space \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

as $x\rightarrow\infty.$

Then since $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0^{+}}\ln(u)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\ln(u)=\infty,$ the integral converges only for $k=\frac{5}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$I_p=\int_{1}^{p} \Big(\frac{5}{2x+6}-\frac{k}{x}\Big)\,dx=\frac{5}{2} \log (p+3)-k \log (p)-5 \log (2)$$
When $p$ is large
$$\log (p+3)=\log (p)+\frac{3}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ making
$$I_p=\left(\frac{5}{2}-k\right) \log (p)-5 \log (2)+\frac{15}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
So, for a finite limit when $p \to \infty$, $k=\frac 52$ seems to be a requirement.